# Ruby what is *args ? An array or? in a method

Tags: ruby

What is *args or *urls if I write a method like:

```
def test(*args)
@test = args
end
```

I have also seen `*urls` is it an array or? Like options are created with hash `options = {}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is to make the function [variadic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) (i.e. the function's arity is an arbitrary number of arguments).

The type is an Array.

Comment: I believe OP asks for the type of `args` rather than its purpose, but I might be wrong in my interpretation. Otherwise yes, that makes the function variadic

Comment: I see. I added a second sentence. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this(it should answer your question):

```
def test *args
  puts args.class
end

test

>> Array
```

Comment: Why use it? why not just write def test(args) ?

Comment: @Railsbeginner I am not saying you should use this function instead of the one you already do. I am just saying you can use this function to check what is the type of the variadic argument like I demonstrate above. I am trying not only to answer the question but also to show you a way to answer yourself.